# Find value in array and return with new from different array

Tags: php, twig

Currently I have two arrays

```
{% set code = [AMS, EIN, RTM] %}
{% set city = [Amsterdam, Eindhoven, Rotterdam] %}
```

I would like to check if the value of `{{airport}}` exists in the first array and if it is `code[0]` I would like to change `{{airport}}` into the value of `city[0]`. Is this possible with Twig?

Comment: Are the `code[0]` and `city[0]` just examples? Or should it apply to all the items of the array?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example. What I meant to explain is that when value #1 is found in code[ ] like to return the #1 value from city [ ] and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the code array:

```
{% for c in code %}
  {# ... #}
{% endfor %}
```

*Documentation:* https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Then if the item does match:

```
{# ... #}
{% if airport == c %}
  {# ... #}
{% endif %}
{# ... #}
```

*Documentation:* https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html

Replace the variable airport, at the same loop index:

```
{# ... #}
{% set airport = city[loop.index0] %}
{# ... #}
```

*Documentation:* https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

So, in full:

```
{% for c in code %}
  {% if airport == c %}
    {% set airport = city[loop. index0] %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Running fiddle: https://twigfiddle.com/xflfas/2

*Out of the scope note*: your arrays would be better named `cities` and `codes`.
This way, when you loop over them, you end up with meaningful naming

```
{% set codes = ['AMS', 'EIN', 'RTM'] %} 
{% for code in codes %}
  {{ code }}
{% endfor %}

{# and #}

{% set cities = ['Amsterdam', 'Eindhoven', 'Rotterdam'] %} 
{% for city in cities %}
  {{ city }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `{% if value in array %}` to search from the first array and Twig's merge function to replace the value in the second array. See this https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html